# Optimize mySQL Query with tuneup server

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I works with mampp and mysql. 
I'd like to optimise mysql server with my.conf 
My goal is to reduce time to execute query.
My query is very simple but I must load in one time all my record (about 40000).
With mampp default parameter, it's take arround 6s to load all the record, I'd like to reduce this time

Can you help me to configure my server.

Thanks a lot

Comment: what for you want to reduce this time?

Comment: more efficient to configure the query, db structure. show us both

Answer (score 0):

When you really load ALL the data from the table (no 'where' clause), I guess you do a lot of sorting? Otherwise it shouldn't take 6 seconds for the query to finish.
So make sure you have an INDEX on all columns that you use for sorting (ORDER BY) or filtering (WHERE) and check if your table cache is large enough to keep your table in memory.

But for more detailed answers you should post your query and your table structure...